# MySQL Trigger-- Not inserting correct values

Tags: mysql, triggers

The goal of this trigger is to insert old data per row into a table if the updated data per row does not equal the current data per row.

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER history BEFORE UPDATE ON table1

FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.salePrice <> OLD.salePrice THEN

INSERT INTO history_price (modelNumber,salePrice)
        VALUES ('modelNumber','OLD.salePrice');

        ELSEIF NEW.salePrice = OLD.salePrice THEN
            SET NEW.salePrice = OLD.salePrice;

    END IF;

 END;//
 delimiter ;
```

All in all, this concept should be working, but the insert is not working. It is only inserting the actual text, not the values.

More specifically:

```
    INSERT INTO history_price (modelNumber,salePrice)
    VALUES 
        ('modelNumber','OLD.salePrice');
```

This part of my trigger literally inserts modelNumber, and OLD.salePrice into my history table if the updated values are not equal.

What is wrong with this query?

Comment: Dont you want to just remove the quotes round the 2 fields? Or am I being stupidly thick?

Comment: I want to insert the values. Im doing an update on those specific fields and I want to insert the old fields' row content.

Comment: I know, but by putting single quotes round the field names, you would be just as good as writing  insert into history_price (modelNumber,salePrice) values ("joe","blogs")

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now. I did not realize that. Wow I was deceivied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modelNumber and OLD.salePrice probably should not be in single quotes.

Comment: This worked. Now, It did INSERT the OLD.salePrice, but it did not Insert the modelNumber

Comment: What happens with modelNumber now?

Comment: I just had to change it OLD.modelNumber

Answer (score 1):

Try then changing it to

```
insert into history_price (old.ModelNumber,old.salePrice)
```